# How do I use < or > in where clauses on collection in Laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel, collections, where-clause

How do I use < or > in where clauses on collection in Laravel? The below is not working:

```
$company['jobs']->where('created_at','>=',$Start_Date)->where('created_at','<=',$End_Date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `orWhere` method:

```php
$company['jobs']->where('created_at', '>=', $Start_Date)
                ->orWhere('created_at', '<=', $End_Date);
```

Alternatively, you can use the `whereBetween` method:

```php
$company['jobs']->whereBetween('created_at', [$Start_Date, $End_Date]);
```

Comment: "Method whereBetween does not exist. " . $company['jobs'] is a collection returned using with('jobs') while querying

Comment: If it's already a collection, you can't query it like that. You'll have to pass your custom logic to `->filter($callback)`.

Comment: can you please explain it more as how i can use two clauses in that logic.

Comment: $filtered = $company['jobs']->filter(function ($item) use($Start_Date,$End_Date) {
                              return $item['created_at'] >= $Start_Date &&  $item['created_at'] <= $End_Date;
                          });    this is the solution .Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is the right solution

```
$filtered = $company['jobs']->filter(function ($item) use($Start_Date,$End_Date) {
                          error_log($item['created_at']);
                          return $item['created_at'] >= $Start_Date &&  $item['created_at'] <= $End_Date;
                      });
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Joseph Silber said, you can create a Scope in your Model to do your own logic. Like this:

```
// Inside your model
public function scopeSearch($query, $field, $value)
        {
            if(is_numeric($value))
                return $query->where($field, '=', "$value");
            elseif(!empty($value))
                return $query->where($field, '=', "$value");
            else
                return $query;
        }
```

Then, you can call it from your controller:

```
$query = Company::search('year',2016);
```